# How to use geographic_msgs?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to write a little client to access osm maps. What I did so far is:

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "Geo");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<geographic_msgs::GetGeographicMap>("geographic_msgs");
geographic_msgs::GetGeographicMap srv;

srv.request.url = "http://openstreetmap.org/node/123456";
if(client.call(srv))
{
     ROS_INFO("connected");
}
else
{
     ROS_ERROR("failed");
}
```

If I run the programm I always get "failed" as an output.
Could anyone tell me how to connect to the maps correctly?

Thanks in advance,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192161/how-to-use-geographic_msgs?/) by [chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20146/chris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-08**:
Is the service running?

**Comment by [chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20146/chris/) on 2014-09-09**:
Unfortunately the service seems not to be running. I tried to run it with rosrun, but there was no executable found. I compiled the Package with catkin_make before and I had no error as a result. In addition the Package seems to be a Metapackage.
So how could I start the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [geographic_info](http://wiki.ros.org/geographic_info) metapackage does not contain any nodes for downloading maps.

Try [osm_cartography](http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography) instead. There's a osm_server node.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20146/chris/) on 2014-09-09**:
I downloaded a part of the map previously and used:

```
srv.request.url = "package:///home/user/map.osm";
```

But this is not working either.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-09**:
If you want to call a service, a server providing that service has to be running.

**Comment by [chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20146/chris/) on 2014-09-09**:
Do you know how the server in this package is called and how I can run it?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-09**:
The wiki page I linked says that the node is called osm_server. And I guess you run it with `rosrun osm_cartography osm_server`.

**Comment by [chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/20146/chris/) on 2014-09-09**:
Thanks for your help

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-09**:
If your question is answered please mark this answer as correct.